# Project Reference Compilation Error

Tags: c#-4.0, project-reference, dll-reference

In my C# solution, there is a web service project in which adding project reference of a class library project does not work, it throws compilation error saying -

> The type or namespace name 'xyz' does not exist in the namespace
>   'abc.pqr' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

abc.pqr.xyz is from the class library being referenced.

while adding dll reference does not throw any compilation error.

I even checked the framework, it is .net framework 4 in both.

One thing more, the project which needs to have a reference was a web service project (Framework 3.5, converted to 4.0).

I added another web service (then converted to 4.0), then added project reference added the same code, compilation goes well.

Issue is with only one project in the solution.

Please help me to figure out the fix.

Comment: No answer! I was expecting a few answers

Comment: Hey Ashish, Not sure if it's the exact same problem, but I fought with something like this for a whole day.

Try moving the web services to a different project solution as a compiled library -- compile it and then add reference to it to all solutions that require it. Worked for me. Visual Studio simply would not allow me to use it in the base library solution. I think the method I described here works because the web service library is compiled before anything else.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Hey Lander, Thanks. I won't be able to move the web service to a another project but will surely try your solution.